# How to validate the value entered by user?

Tags: php, laravel-5

`$temp->Pid="GC".$form1->input('Pid');`

In this code, I get the value from the form and need to validate it whether it already exists in db.

Comment: show us the part of your code with the query

Comment: Put a unique key on that column in your database and simply _try_ to insert it. If it succeeds - fine, otherwise you get a clear error.

Comment: You can also check Laravel's documentation about validation (specifically the rule `unique`) https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Will you please mention that how to give  unique key by coding with laravel migrations  @arkascha

Comment: Again, Laravel's documentation to the resucue. To make a column unique, read about migrations and indexes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: You're using one of the most popular frameworks that has an extensive documentation. That would be a good starting point when you hit a snag or wondering about something.

Answer (score 0):

Query your table with the input to test for results, if nothing comes back then you know it doesn't already exist.

```
MyModel::where('Pid', 'GC')->get()
```

check if that returns anything.

Comment: not only with 'GC' sir .I need validate the entire textfield of Pid

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation and check for the existance by the following way

**Step 1 : Check for Validation**

```
$validation = Validator::make($loginData, YourModel::$yourValidation);
if ($validation->passes()) {
//passes Validation    
}
```

**Step 2 : Check for existance**

```
$data = YourModel::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Now together all, You can do like this

```
$validation = Validator::make($loginData, YourModel::$yourValidation);
if ($validation->passes()) {
$data = YourModel::where('id', $id)->first();
$Response = array('success' => '1', 'data' => $data);
}
else
{
$Response = array('success' => '0', 'err' => $validation->messages());
}
return $Response;
```

Hope this helps you,

**Note :**

You need to change your Model and Validator accordingly